# Why are SVG strokes semi-transparent

Tags: svg, graphics

I have an SVG diagram that consists of many `<path>` elements some of which overlap.  The problem I'm having is that where the path overlap, the colour of the first element shows through on the second changing its colour.  I've tried to use the `stroke-opacity` property but this doesn't fix the issue.  I then noticed that when the stroke is larger than 1px, the top colour shows as expected but with fringes of the colour behind on the edges.  Is there any way to stop this?  Thanks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg height="80" width="300">
  <g fill="none" stroke-width="1">
    <path stroke="red" d="M5 20 l215 0" />
    <path stroke="black" d="M5 20 l215 0" />
  </g>
     <text x="0" y="12">1px stroke shows as brown rather than black</text>
      <g fill="none" stroke-width="4">
    <path stroke="red" d="M5 50 l215 0" />
    <path stroke="black" d="M5 50 l215 0" />
  </g>
  <text x="0" y="40">Larger than 1px has overfringing</text>
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/A/antialiasing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add shape-rendering to your SVG elements :

```
shape-rendering: auto | optimizeSpeed | crispEdges | geometricPrecision | initial | inherit
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering

Comment: Thanks!  `crispEdges` did want I wanted to an extent but caused some lines to thin and angled lines to alias. `geometricPrecision` produced a visually better image but on closer inspection, the lines looked smoothed.  But it was good enough!